Hello all. I have a question about my wifi adapter
I have installed am Alfa adapter and updated the driver. When I run iwconfig I see Wlan0 and my device. I cannot seem to get it to start monitoring, though.
It is in managed mode.
I need some help disconnecting my internet WiFi card. I don't have the commands. I have removed Windows 11 and am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

It's helpful if you're specific with details; you mention running the latest Ubuntu, so it's Ubuntu 24.10; but you don't state if this is Ubuntu 24.10 Server? or Ubuntu 24.10 Desktop?

sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
